# Split a string, but keep the delimiter in C

Tags: c, string, strtok

I am trying to split a string that contains operands and operator. 
`1+2+3*3/2`
The operands and operator will be saved into a separate linked List.

I managed to split the string using `strtok()`.

Currently, my program returns `1 2 3 3 2` after the function `strtok()`, however I want to keep my delimiters `++*/`. How can I do this? Is there another kind of function in C, similar to strtok(), which will also return/save the delimiters?

Comment: For parsing expressions it's usually best to go through the input character by character, collecting digits into arrays that can be terminated as string and then converted to numbers. Then it's easy to keep track of the "delimiter" (operator) in the input.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i've thought about that method, however there will also be numbers that are >9 i.e. i will also have to store numbers such as `1598` as a whole into one node.

Comment: No, there is no such bult-in function. You can write one using strcapn for example. But consider using a more generic lexical analyser instead.

Comment: That's why I said that you should collect digits into an array that can be used as a string. For the input `1598` you put the characters `'1'`, `'5'`, `'9'` and `'8'` into an array, add the null-terminator, and [convert to a number](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol)

Comment: @someprogrammerdude: or you could take the much simpler approach of leaving the string where it is and letting `strtoul` tell you where the number ends.